# Where is java command located in Android?

Tags: android, filesystems

I got my android phone rooted and I'm aware that the `/` doesn't contain the familiar linux `/`.

Is there a `java` command? Where is it located? I don't find one in `/system/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a `java` command?

No. Such a command isn't shipped with stock *Android* images.

> Where is it located?

It shouldn't exist on filesystem. What makes you think it should be there?

> I don't find one in `/system/bin`.

You might consider installing any *Java* programming app for *Android* to have *JDK/JRE* installed. In this case the command will be located in the app's sandbox, not `/system/bin`.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not use Java at all, at runtime.

Android runs programs that have been written in the Java language.  Those programs are not compiled to Java bytecodes and will not run on a JVM.

Android executes Dalvik bytecodes.  Until somewhere around Android 4, it used a virtual machine called Dalvik, to execute these bytecodes.  Now it uses fantastically more complex virtual machine called ART.

Sorry.  No Java.